# Reading from SQL Server database then reading the top 3 values and output them into labels in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to read the top three values from my database and output them into separate labels.

This is the code I have so far:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FastHostSS_homeConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

var readDomain = ("SELECT tldName FROM tld");

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(readDomain, conn);

SqlDataReader myReader = com.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    Domain1_lb.Text = (myReader["TOP 1 tldName"].ToString());
    Domain2_lb.Text = (myReader["TOP 2 tldName"].ToString());
    Domain3_lb.Text = (myReader["TOP 3 tldName"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: if you only want 3 change your SQL to only select top 3 as well

Comment: How do I read 3 different rows and output them into different labels?

Comment: Brad, that makes everything one value, I want the top three, different values

Comment: Look into the `GROUP BY` sql function. It will become something like `SELECT TOP (3) tldName, COUNT(tldName) AS count FROM tld GROUP BY tldName ORDER BY count DESC`

Comment: you just select top 3 so you dont get tons of records returned.  Add an if statement in your while, and you can say if rownumber = 1 set lable 1 to value, if rownumber = 2 and so on

Comment: Sounds like you want "DISTINCT" if I understand you correctly.

Comment: It would really help if you explained what you mean by “top 3”. For example the SQL `TOP` clause only makes sense if you have an `ORDER BY` clause, and your query doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide which label to assign to based on the loop count.

```
int index = 0;
while (myReader.Read())
{
    var tld = myReader["tldName"].ToString();
    ++index;
    if(index == 1) Domain1_lb.Text = tld;
    if(index == 2) Domain2_lb.Text = tld;
    if(index == 3) Domain3_lb.Text = tld;
}
```

This is nowadays normally done using data binding, where a framework takes care of the assignments.